# How do I update message feed in my Android app

Tags: android, android-workmanager

This is hypothetical.

Let's say I'm building an app that has a message feed. I could use WorkManager but it schedules network calls every 15 minutes.

Obviously can't wait 15 minutes to get a new message from a friend.

What are the alternatives?

Comment: See [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#using_fcm)

Comment: Isn't there something native to Android that I can use?

Comment: Firebase is owned by Google and [FCM requires Google Play Services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services). While there may be other providers, those are probably whitelisted by ODMs as battery saving measures beyond [Doze mode on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) is so common that https://dontkillmyapp.com/ exists.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime messaging platform is done through sockets. Network sockets allows communication to goes both ways.
Your server will notify the client (Android app in this case) when new message will arrive and the client will send data when you create a new message.

If you want to build something like this, Firebase have support for realtime database, but if you just want to get more familiar with the topic you should dig into Server-Client socket communication.

Comment: Okay. Can't I just use a Service to get periodic updates? Like WorkManager but every few seconds or so.

Comment: Well, yes you can, it's not ideal solution, but it will work. I don't have all the info on what you want to build. Another idea if you don't want to bother with sockets is to use Push Notifications, for each new message send a push notification, if the app is in foreground don't display the push just fetch the message and update the UI accordingly. 
Hope this answer was helpful to you :)